# Return all wows, mached and unmatched in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables and i'm like to query 2 tables to obtain a report.

```
POSITION
+-------------+---------------+
| position_id | position_name |
+-------------+---------------+
|     1       |     E1P1      |
|     2       |     E1P2      |
|     3       |     E3P3      |
|     4       |     E4P4      |
+-------------+---------------+   

PEOPLE
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
| people_id  | people_name | people_position_id |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
|     1      |    JOHN     |         2          |
|     2      |    MARK     |         4          |
+------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

QUERY

```
SELECT position_id, position_name, people_name FROM position
RIGHT JOIN people ON people_position_id = position_id
```

When I use simple query I get only matched rows, ho to obtain all?

**I'm like to obtain this result**

```
+----+----------+--------+
| ID | POSITION | STATUS |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  |   E1P1   | Empty  |
| 2  |   E1P2   | JOHN   |
| 3  |   E3P3   | Empty  |
| 4  |   E4P4   | MARK   |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a left join here:

```
SELECT
    po.position_id,
    po.position_name,
    COALESCE(pe.people_name, 'EMPTY') AS STATUS
FROM position po
LEFT JOIN people pe
    ON po.position_id = pe.people_position_id;
```

By the way, the reason your current right join attempt is failing is that you have placed the `people` table on the right side of the join.  This means that non matching position records would be discarded.  Here is my answer above, rewritten using a right join:

```
SELECT
    po.position_id,
    po.position_name,
    COALESCE(pe.people_name, 'EMPTY') AS STATUS
FROM people pe
RIGHT JOIN position po
    ON po.position_id = pe.people_position_id;
```

Note carefully that the table order has switched.  Most of the time, you will see people using left joins rather than right joins.

Comment: Try adding an index on `people`, e.g. `CREATE INDEX idx ON people (people_position_id, people_name)`.  This alone should speed things up a bit.